# Losing selected text focus on Value change

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend

I am writing a time display component. The value changes every second, whenever I am trying to copy the text it loses the focus because value changes. Current Epoch for example in below image  [image]

```
 const [currentEpoch, setCurrentEpoch] = useState(initialEpoch);
const [localTime, setLocalTime] = useState(initialLocalTime);
const [utcTime, setUtcTime] = useState(initialUtcTime);

const [convertEpoch, setConvertEpoch] = useState<{ localDate: string, utcDate: string } | null>();

useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        setCurrentEpoch(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
        setLocalTime(new Date().toString());
        setUtcTime(new Date().toUTCString());
    }, 1000);
}, []);
```

Comment: You've provided 0 code, so I'll guess you're probably using `useState` for the time value. Each time it changes, the component will re-render. Try moving them in different components if this is the case.

Comment: I didn't think you will need code but here it is. Check now

Comment: As I stated above, have you tried moving the element from which you wish to copy out of the component ?